# Budget Mandalorian backgrounds

Tags: video, projector

If I have a projector, an iphone with (basic) motion tracking, and a fast-ish computer running Unreal or something similar, has anyone figured out a way to make [Mandalorian-style responsive backdrops](https://youtu.be/8yNkBic7GfI) on a tiny budget, by using the iPhone’s motion tracking, or something similar? Seems like it might be possible soon?

Comment: Soon? Definitely not. That tech has taken 25 years to make its way from the £20M cave systems for one person, to Vox, which is similar in cost, but makes it simpler for multiple persons+cameras.

Comment: Wasn't there a hack for the Wii about a decade ago that did this?

Comment: Yes. 12 years ago. That’s why I’m surprised there’s nothing more formalised since then. I could see it being useful: https://youtu.be/Jd3-eiid-Uw

Answer (score 1):

Update - this is the closest thing I've found, but you need to use Unreal and have a fast graphics card: